# AngularJS filters not working when data loaded from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to learn angular with firebase. I'm getting data and successfully output it. But after this, simple filters not working with this data. When i'm doing simple $http.get from the same, but local json file, filters works just fine.
My application module/controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('testSite', ['ngRoute', 'angControllers', 'firebase'])
.value('fbURL', 'https://sizzling-fire-3696.firebaseio.com/')
.factory('personData', function($firebase, fbURL) {
    return $firebase(new Firebase(fbURL));
});
app.controller("angCont", ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
 'personData', 
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, personData) {
        $scope.data = personData;
}]);
```

And this is my html template:

```
<div ng-controller="angCont">
    <select ng-model="personSelectFilter" ng-options="person.name for person in data">
        <option value="">Filter by name</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="personInputFilter" placeholder="Filter">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in data | filter: personInputFilter |
     filter: personSelectFilter | orderBy: personSorting">
    Name: <a href="#/persons/{{person.name}}">{{person.name}}</a><br/>
    Surname: {{person.surname}}<br/>
    Age: {{person.age | number}}<br/>
    Experience (months): {{person.exp | number}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://angulartest.hostoi.com/angsite.html#/

Comment: Can you show a link? That definitely should not be happening.

Comment: I'm trying it on localserver. Or stuff like that is not supposed to work on localhost?

Comment: Well, its client side, so it should work the same regardless.

Comment: All i can say, that data from firebase loading with delay about 0.5-1 second. But it's loads only in ng-repeat ul-li. Select with ng-options  is empty like nothing happend. And simpliest input filters not working too.

Comment: http://angulartest.hostoi.com/angsite.html#/ - demo on freehosting site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$firebase always creates an object, so the `data` variable contains key/value pairs. However, filter and orderBy in Angular expect an array. This can be corrected by using `orderByPriority`, which is covered in the AngularFire docs under [Ordered Data and Arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#orderbypriority).

```
<li ng-repeat="person in data | orderByPriority | filter: personInputFilter |
    filter: personSelectFilter | orderBy: personSorting">
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i needed! Thank you, i definitely was googling wrong questions about filters and other stuff.

Comment: It should probably be part of the angularFire tutorial or getting started guide.

Comment: wow that is a long filter chain. No prob for learning, but be careful with those digest permutations.